# magento - open popup window after admin login

Tags: magento

I want to show pop-up window when admin successfully logs in. I have a custom module `Setstore_Notification` with config.xml file -

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Setstore_Notification>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Setstore_Notification>
  </modules>
  <global>
  <events>
    <admin_session_user_login_success>
      <observers>
        <Setstore_Notification_customer_register_success>
          <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Setstore_Notification_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>choosestore</method>
        </Setstore_Notification_customer_register_success>
     </observers>
    </admin_session_user_login_success>
  </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

and observer file in Model -

```
<?php
class Setstore_Notification_Model_Observer {
    public function choosestore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();        

        -----


    }
}
?>
```

I didn't understand how should I call a popup window in observer file. I have `window.js` included in dashboard page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by rendering a block

```
$this->loadLayout();
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$block = $layout->getBlock("hello");
echo $block->toHtml();
```

Inside hello block would be

```
<script>doPopup();</script>
```

Yet another way render a cms page

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
    ->setBlockId('idOfMyCmsPage')
    ->toHtml();
```